# what this stament means? Z = A(xxx:xxx + w- 1, yyy:yyy+ w- 1, :);

Tags: matlab, indexing

In a program in MATLAB I found the following statement but i cannot make out what that means.

```
Z = A(xxx:xxx + w- 1, yyy:yyy+ w- 1, :);
```

A is in an index (n,n,3)
xxx , yyy, w are integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A is a 3 dimensional matrix. In that statement you are reading a range of cells from that matrix. In Matlab a:b means from a to b, and a colon (:) on its own means 'everything'.

```
Lets say that xxx=5, yyy=10 and w=2. Then in your case you are reading:
1st dimension (rows) : from 5 to 6 (6 = 5 + 2 - 1)
2nd dimension (columns) : from 10 to 11 (11 = 10 + 2 - 1) 
3rd dimension (pages) : all of the pages.
```

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://www.math.utah.edu/~eyre/computing/matlab-intro/matrices.html) that may be useful to you. Also, please mark this question as answered by clicking the very good icon